# Fish shell installation using homebrew - iconv libiconv error

Tags: terminal, homebrew, command-line

I am trying to install **Fish** shell using **homebrew** using command:

```
brew install fish
```

But the installation fails with the following error:

```
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/fish/2.1.1 SED=/usr/bin/sed
checking for library containing setupterm... -lncurses
checking for library containing nan... none required
checking for library containing iconv_open... no
checking for library containing libiconv_open... no
configure: error: Could not find an iconv implementation, needed to build fish
```

I tried searching around but no clear solution was found. System configuration:

```
$ brew --config
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 0.9.5
ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew.git
HEAD: f03104755df8cbfb720254bd88ac7594a3837d36
Last commit: 11 hours ago
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_CELLAR: /usr/local/Cellar
CPU: quad-core 64-bit haswell
OS X: 10.10.1-x86_64
CLT: 6.1.0.0.1.1413057044
Clang: 6.0 build 600
X11: N/A
System Ruby: 2.0.0-481
Perl: /usr/bin/perl
Python: /usr/bin/python
Ruby: /usr/bin/ruby
```

Could you please help to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Can you add what the output from `brew doctor` is? This is usually a great first step to fixing build problems.

Comment: brew doctor does not tell anything unfortunately. Have a look at full log: https://gist.github.com/kmisiunas/cd7496a8fdaedba3c9a5

Comment: Nothing there indeed.. I'm able to get it to build on my system, only difference being that I have XCode installed (`brew --config` shows `Xcode: 6.1` where yours does not), and i've got a newer version of Brew installed (commit ends in `37d36`, and I saw that the `fish` package got an update). Try doing a `brew update`, and if that fails, installing Xcode from the appstore.

Oddly enough, if I try to do a `brew install libiconv`', I get a message back saying `Apple distributes libiconv with OS X`. Smells like a pathing problem of some kind.

Comment: Just installed XCode 6.1. The same problem. I suspect the problem is deeper. I agree with your pathing hypothesis - just not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Just realised. You have an `/opt` folder. Have you installed MacPorts?

Comment: @AlistairMcMillan, I did not have MacPorts installed. But I might have had it ages ago so I went though full uninstall procedure (https://guide.macports.org/#installing.macports.uninstalling). Now installing Fish worked! Thank you! Do you know what happened?

Comment: @karolis My guess is remnants of that MacPorts install that were confusing brew. From the log you posted above it seemed to be checking `/opt/local` (which MacPorts uses) before `/usr/local` (which brew uses).

Comment: @AlistairMcMillan ok. Thanks for the insight! Would you like to post a quick answer?

Comment: @Karolis Updated my previous answer. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the log that you posted above the following three lines suggest that you have MacPorts installed.

```
checking for /opt/local/include include directory... yes
checking for /opt/local/lib library directory... yes
checking for /opt/local/bin command directory... yes
```

It also appears that brew is checking there before checking in its regular file locations (`/usr/local`, etc). Something under `/opt` might be confusing brew and preventing it from compiling fish.

This can be mended by following MacPorts uninstall guide: [guide.macports.org/#installing.macports.uninstalling](http://guide.macports.org/#installing.macports.uninstalling)

Comment: It seems to be already installed. Response was: "xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed"